# How to access Azure Storage Logs via http?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have seen literature that indicates you should be able to access log files in an Azure storage container (`somectr`) with a url like:

```
http://somectr.blob.core.windows.net/$logs?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=blob/2015/08/28/0900/000000.log
```

And get a directory of log files from that date with:

```
http://somectr.blob.core.windows.net/$logs?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=blob/2015/08/
```

But I get a 404 error when I do this. I think this is indicating that there are no access rights on the object.

I can see the log file in Azure Storage Explorer, and even view it, but Storage Explorer will not let me edit access rights on this container (although I can on other (non-system) containers). The actual log file is listed, and is there (and I can even view it with the explorer, but I want http access to it.

I also can't even see the $log container in the Azure Portal or the Azure Preveiw Portal, where I might be able to grant public access or something.

Is the reference that I found wrong? Is http-browser access to logs not possible, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because the ACL of `$logs` container is set as `Private` thus unauthenticated requests are failing with 404 (Not Found) error. <del>Please change the ACL of this container from `Private` to `Blob` (or `Container`) and then you should be able to access the logs directly.</del>

**UPDATE**

Since `$logs` is a system generated container, you can't change it's ACL (and this is why you're getting this 403 error when you're trying to perform this operation). What you would need to do instead is create a `Shared Access Signature` on this container with `Read` and `List` permissions. You can use Azure Storage Explorer for that only (see screenshot below).

[image]

To list blobs in the that container, simply add `comp=list&restype=container` to the SAS URL. When you put that URL in your browser's address bar, you should be able to see the list of the blobs.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="http://account.blob.core.windows.net/" ContainerName="$logs">
        <Blobs>
            <Blob>
                <Name>blob/2015/01/16/1300/000000.log</Name>
                <Properties>
                    <Last-Modified>Fri, 16 Jan 2015 13:50:16 GMT</Last-Modified><Etag>0x8D1FFAA7E1ECE77</Etag>
                    <Content-Length>1819</Content-Length>
                    <Content-Type>application/octet-stream</Content-Type>
                    <Content-Encoding />
                    <Content-Language />
                    <Content-MD5 />
                    <Cache-Control />
                    <Content-Disposition />
                    <BlobType>BlockBlob</BlobType>
                    <LeaseStatus>unlocked</LeaseStatus>
                    <LeaseState>available</LeaseState>
                </Properties>
            </Blob>
        </Blobs>
    </EnumartionResults>
...
```

To view blob, just insert the blob name in the SAS URL just after `container name` and before `?` as shown below:

> http://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/$logs/blob/2015/01/16/1300/000000.log?sv=2014-02-14&sr=c&sig=sAmaOtRqXqyedQEfmDGsoCPxGXUUcMO43GhimoPjbxA%3D&st=2015-09-01T18%3A30%3A00Z&se=2015-09-09T18%3A30%3A00Z&sp=rl

Once you paste this URL in the browser's address bar, you should be able to see the logs.

Comment: That is what I thought, but how can I change the ACL? Are there only API solutions?

Comment: I haven't used Azure Storage Explorer in a while, but you should be able to change the ACL. Other than that, there are many storage explorers that support this functionality. HTH.

Comment: It has the functionality, but I get "Error settiing blob container permisions: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." That is of course my question really. I already had gotten this far.

Comment: Are you getting 403 error just on this operation or other operations as well?

Comment: Just when I try to change the permissions on the $log container. Everything else works fine. I can also change the permissions on other containers in this storage account, just not the $log container. Feels like it is by design (Azure Storage Design).

Comment: Hmmmmm...that's weird! Let me try it out and get back to you. What version of Azure Storage Explorer are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry ... my bad :(. `$logs` is a special container and you can't change its ACL. We would need to do it another way. Let me update my answer in a little while.

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.